# Why no emplacement iterators in C++11 or C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, c++14

C++98 has `front_inserter`, `back_inserter`, and `inserter`, but there don't seem to be any emplacement versions of these in C++11 or draft C++14. Is there any technical reason we couldn't have `front_emplacer`, `back_emplacer`, and `emplacer`?

Comment: What are you going to assign into them? Tuples of arguments?

Comment: @PavelAnossov: It would allow conversions constructors at least `*front_inserter(string_vector) = "hello world";`

Comment: @MooingDuck: that already works with inserters

Comment: @PavelAnossov: But because the inserters insist on inserting an object of the type held by the container, you pay a penalty (typically a move) for inserting a different type. Emplacement would avoid that penalty.

Comment: Can you give a sensible use case?

Comment: @Walter: Use Case 1: I have a container of ints and a container of objects, where each object can be initialized with an int. I want to append to the container of objects a sequence of new objects initialized with the ints, and I want to do it maximally efficiently. Use case 2: I have a library of algorithms in the STL style, but they operate on multiple input sequences at once (like the two-sequence version of std::transform). I want to add new objects to the front of a sequence, where the new objects' n constructor arguments are taken from the n input sequences I'm processing.

Comment: @Walter: inserting into an array of objects where the objects are large and/or legacy types that are copiable but not movable .  It's not exactly a stretch.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe The problem is that `back_emplacer`, when used with algorithms, would accept only a single constructor argument (such as your `int`). Algorithms such as `std::generate` do no provide possibility to pass multiple arguments to be forwarded to `back_emplacer`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there any technical reason we couldn't have front_emplacer, back_emplacer, and emplacer?

No, there is no technical reason.  As proof, here is a complete implementation of `back_emplacer` with a demo of your Use Case 1...

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class Container>
class back_emplace_iterator : public std::iterator< std::output_iterator_tag,
                                                   void, void, void, void >
{
protected:
    Container* container;
public:
    typedef Container container_type;

    explicit back_emplace_iterator(Container& x) : container(&x) {}

    template<class T>
    back_emplace_iterator<Container>&
    operator=(T&& t)
    {
        container->emplace_back(std::forward<T>(t));
        return *this;
    }

    back_emplace_iterator& operator*() { return *this; }
    back_emplace_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
    back_emplace_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }
};

template< class Container >
inline back_emplace_iterator<Container>
back_emplacer( Container& c )
{
    return back_emplace_iterator<Container>(c);
}

struct Demo
{
    int i;
    Demo(int i) : i(i) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4,5};

    std::vector<Demo> y;

    std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), back_emplacer(y));

    for (auto d : y)
        std::cout << d.i << std::endl;
}
```

Possible Known Issue:  Does the universal reference of `operator=` hide an implicitly generated copy/move `operator=`?  If so these need to be explicitly defined in a way that beats the universal reference in overload resolution.

Comment: I have [asked another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728257/back-emplacer-implementation-default-operator) regarding the known issue.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Proxy class for what?  Go have a look at the libstdc++ implementation of `back_inserter`.  It is in `bits/stl_iterator.h`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: So it is required by the C++ standard to not use a proxy class, but to implement it the way shown.  See N3485 24.5.2.2.3.

Comment: Existence proofs are awesome :-)  I'm marking this as the answer. Thanks for the great work!

Comment: @user1131467: Wow, so it is.  That's strange to me, I wonder why they decided to do it that way?

Comment: Is the advantage of this over plain `back_inserter_iterator`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303852/is-there-a-back-inserter-variant-that-takes-advantage-of-move/54304086#54304086

Comment: @alfC: Yeah I now think the notion of `back_emplace_iterator` is conceptually flawed.  "emplace"-style operations take a pack of arguments and then forward them to the constructor.  See for example `std::vector::emplace_back`.  Such an operation does not fit into the iterator paradigm, because the underlying iterator abstraction does not support it.

Answer (score 8):

Your main use case is already covered by `inserter`, `back_inserter` and `front_inserter`. There is already a `value_type &&` overload of `operator=` that will move into the container. The only thing `emplacer` could do over `inserter` is call explicit constructors.

Compare the common overloads of `container::insert`, `container::push_back` and `container::push_front` to `container::emplace`, `container::emplace_back` and `container::emplace_front`

```
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const value_type & value );
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, value_type && value );

template< class... Args > 
iterator emplace( const_iterator pos, Args&&... args );

void push_back( const value_type & value );
void push_back( value_type && value );

template< class... Args >
void emplace_back( Args&&... args );

void push_front( const value_type & value );
void push_front( value_type && value );

template< class... Args >
void emplace_front( Args&&... args );
```

Each of the `emplace` variants takes a pack of arguments with which to construct the value. `operator =` takes exactly one argument. You could write an `emplacer` that took a tuple of arguments.

```
template<class Container>
class back_emplace_iterator : public std::iterator< std::output_iterator_tag,
                                                   void, void, void, void >
{
protected:
    Container* container;
public:
    typedef Container container_type;

    explicit back_emplace_iterator(Container& x) : container(&x) {}

    template<typename ... Args>
    back_emplace_iterator<Container>&
    operator=(std::tuple<Args&&...> args)
    {
        std::apply(Container::emplace_back, std::tuple_cat(std::tie(*container), std::forward<std::tuple<Args&&...>>(args)));
        return *this;
    }

    back_emplace_iterator& operator*() { return *this; }
    back_emplace_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
    back_emplace_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }
};
```