# Wrapping a legacy C API in C++ with write iterator support

Tags: c++, c++14, cpython

I have a legacy C API to a container-like object (specifically, the Python C API to tuples) which I would like to wrap in a nice C++14 API, so that I can use an iterator. How should I go about implementing this?

Here's some more details.  We have the following existing C API which cannot be changed:

```
Py_ssize_t PyTuple_GET_SIZE(PyObject *p);
PyObject* PyTuple_GET_ITEM(PyObject *p, Py_ssize_t pos);
void PyTuple_SET_ITEM(PyObject *p, Py_ssize_t pos, PyObject *o)
```

We want to create a class which allows you to get access to a read/write iterator on the elements in the tuple.

The forward read-only iterator is not too difficult to define.  Here is what I have:

```
class PyTuple {
private:
  PyObject* tuple;

public:
  PyTuple(PyObject* tuple) : tuple(tuple) {}

  class iterator {
    // iterator traits
    PyObject* tuple;
    Py_ssize_t index;
  public:
    iterator(PyObject *tuple, Py_ssize_t index) : tuple(tuple), index(index) {}
    iterator& operator++() { index++; return *this; }
    iterator operator++(int) { auto r = *this; ++(*this); return r; }
    bool operator==(iterator other) const { return tuple == other.tuple && index == other.index; }
    bool operator!=(iterator other) const { return !(*this == other); }
    PyObject* operator*() { return PyTuple_GET_ITEM(tuple, index); }
    // iterator traits
    using difference_type = Py_ssize_t;
    using value_type = PyObject*;
    using pointer = PyObject**;
    using reference = PyObject*&;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
  };

  iterator begin() {
    return iterator(tuple, 0);
  }

  iterator end() {
    return iterator(tuple, PyTuple_GET_SIZE(tuple));
  }
}
```

However, I am not too sure how to support writes. I have to somehow make `*it = pyobj_ptr` work. Conventionally, this would be done by changing the type to `PyObject*& operator*()` (so that it gives an lvalue) but I can't do this because the tuple "write" needs to go through `PyTuple_SET_ITEM`. I have heard that you can use `operator=` to solve this case but I am not sure if I should use a universal reference ([Why no emplacement iterators in C++11 or C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724999/why-no-emplacement-iterators-in-c11-or-c14)) or a proxy class ([What is Proxy Class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994488/what-is-proxy-class-in-c)), and am not exactly sure what the code should look like exactly.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938871/315052

Comment: You should consider using std::iterator as a base for your iterators.

Comment: std::iterator has been deprecated as of C++17 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated so I think we're not supposed to use it anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is basically a proxy reference. You don't want to dereference into `PyObject*`, you want to dereference into something that itself can give you a `PyObject*`. This is similar to how the iterators for types like `vector<bool>` behave.

Basically, you want `operator*()` to give you something like:

```
class PyObjectProxy {
public:
    // constructors, etc.

    // read access
    operator PyObject*() const { return PyTuple_GET_ITEM(tuple, index); }

    // write access
    void operator=(PyObject* o) {
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tuple, index, o); // I'm guessing here
    }
private:
    PyObject* tuple;
    Py_ssize_t index;  
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains things nicely! I have a few extra questions: (1) in the SO link about emplacement iterators, it is mentioned that the C++ standard requires certain iterators NOT to use proxies. Why was this restriction levied? (2) I noticed for OutputIterator, the idiom is to define the `*` operator as `return *this`. IIUC, this doesn't work for reads?

Comment: To put it differently, the proxy object looks weirdly the same as the iterator object (field-wise), but I guess it is not possible to use the same thing in both cases?

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang I don't understand either question, or how they're related to this one. It's better to use different types to solve different problems.

Comment: @edward you cannot create a conformant random access iterator that uses such proxy iterators.  The same is true of many iterator categories, but not all.