# Is there a back_inserter variant that takes advantage of move?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move, push-back

In generic code I was trying to tell an output iterator (in practice a `std::back_inserter_iterator` to move a range of elements. To my surprise it looked as if elements were moved in a move-to-back_inserter operation.

```
#include<algorithm> // move
#include<iterator> // back_inserter
#include<vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > v(10, std::vector<double>(100));
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > w;

    assert( not v[0].empty() and w.size() == 0 );
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(w));
    assert( not v[0].empty() and w.size() == 10 );

    std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(w));
    assert( v[0].empty() and w.size() == 20 ); // were v elements moved to w?
}
```

However I don't think it is possible that elements of `v` were really moved to `w`, because after all `back_inserter` will do a `push_back` which implies a copy to `w`.

It seems more likely that in the `std::move` case, `v` elements were moved to a temporary and only then copied into `w`.

**Is that correct? Is there a `std::back_inserter` really moving somehow?**

**Is there already a variant of `std::back_inserter` that takes advantage of move/emplace?** Something like an `std::back_emplacer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::back_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) is a convenience function template for creating an [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator/operator%3D) object.

The class `std::back_insert_iterator` has already `operator=` overloaded for taking *rvalue reference* types, i.e.:

```
back_insert_iterator<Container>& operator=(typename Container::value_type&& value);
```

Therefore, `std::back_insert_iterator` is already prepared to take advantage of move semantics.

Comment: I missed both that `back_inserter_iterator` has `operator=(T&&)` and that `push_back` also has a `T&&`.

Answer (score 3):

If `std::back_insert_iterator` does nothing but calling `push_back` on the container it's being constructed with, the question can be answered looking at the [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) overload set:

```
void push_back(const T& value);
void push_back(T&& value);
```

So, here we obviously have an overload for rvalue references. Wouldn't it be weird, if the corresponding `std::back_insert_iterator` copies its argument when invoked with an rvalue reference? And indeed, we again have a very similar [overload set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator/operator%3D):

```
// 1
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
    operator=(typename Container::const_reference value);
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
    operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value);

// 2
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
    operator=(typename Container::value_type&& value);
```

with the additional comment that

> 1. Results in container->push_back(value)
> 2. Results in container->push_back(std::move(value))

Coming back to your original question

> Is there a std::back_inserter really moving somehow?

Yes, the iterator this function creates does take advantage of rvalue reference arguments.

> Is there already a variant of std::back_inserter that takes advantage of move/emplace?

No, but it can be implemented. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18726119/9593596).

Comment: I missed that, I was convinced that `push_back` only had a `const T&` overload. That added to the fact that `back_inserter_iterator` has `::operator=(T&&)` makes a `back_emplacer` much less necessary.

Comment: @alfC I guess you are getting confused with emplace vs move. Move of the contents - so avoiding a copy and delete - is the much simpler feature to implement, and you can pretty much assume it is everywhere in the stl. With emplace, you provide the arguments necessary to construct the object, and call a special xxx_emplace() method to have the object constructed directly into the container space. This can, of course, be a move constructor, but that is generally not necessary to emplace if all you want to do is move.

Comment: @GemTaylor yes, but if you are talking about emplace with a single argument of value type. Then push_back(move(t)) is no worst or better than emplace_back(move(t)). Is it?

Comment: @alfC No it shouldn't be much different, assuming your object implements move semantics efficiently, and the core object itself is not so big that copying those simple members is not expensive. For example, moving a string means copying at least 24 bytes of the string object itself. Emplace avoids those 24 bytes: nothing compared to allocating a new string, copying the contents, and deleting the old string, but not zero.

Comment: To be clear, emplace_back of a char* into a vector of string will save this small additional copy and clear of the 24byte string object itself vs. push_back of the same char* - of course the string has to be copied once to dynamic memory in both cases, which is a much more expensive operation. But compare this to c++98, when push_back of char* would create a temporary string, then dup the dynamic content, then delete the first dynamic instance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there already a variant of std::back_inserter that takes advantage
> of move/emplace? Something like an std::back_emplacer?

There is back_emplacer described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131700/7471760

But it is not part of std.

See also:
[Why no emplacement iterators in C++11 or C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724999/why-no-emplacement-iterators-in-c11-or-c14)