# How can I Achieve Construction Within Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, constructor, iteration, fill

Given a data structure which has a user defined constructor taking a parameter, something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const int) {}
};
```

And given 2 `vector`s of the same size: `vector<int> input` and `vector<Foo> output`. I'd like to be able to do this:

```
copy(cbegin(input), cend(input), begin(output))
```

Is there a way I can tell `copy` or some other standard algorithm to construct a `Foo` from the `int` that is being iterated over?

Comment: `std::transform` is your friend.

Comment: Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724999/why-no-emplacement-iterators-in-c11-or-c14/18726119

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yeah that's what I was doing now. It's just annoying to have to write a lambda when the constructor is right there.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo That is pretty much what I want. I take it from the presence of that question that it isn't possible to do this with the tools already available to us in the standard?

Comment: You need a `back_inserter` if you want to use copy to create the objects.

Comment: @NathanOliver Clever, so I can't do this with the `vector`s already being the same size, but I can construct when using `back_inserter`. That's not a perfect answer, but I can do a reserve before, so I think it works well enough. I'd accept if you wrote up an answer.

Comment: It's already closed to a Q that shows it so no need.  You can't use a pre-sized vector but you can use one that has been `reserved` so you don't have unnecessary allocations but this should have better performance because constructing a bunch of default object to just reassign them is wasteful.

Comment: It seems to me like [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) already calls `Foo::Foo(const int)`, as there are no other conversion mechanisms available. Maybe you can share the complete code to reproduce the issue?